Predatory first-time strike
Here's a football (soccer) match report from the BBC. I don't understand the word "predatory" in this context. It usually means denoting an animal preying naturally on others. But it doesn't seem to mean that. What does it exactly mean?

Delap's two goals were both well taken but quite different in
execution.
His first was a predatory first-time strike from inside the
penalty area and his second was all of his own making, reminiscent of
his first Premier League goal for Ipswich in the 1-1 draw against
Fulham on 31 August.


Dictionaries give many other meanings for predatory. You should consult a range of dictionaries before posting here.

Not the main focus of the question, but "first-time strike" is a shot where the player doesn't dribble or control the ball first; the ball is passed towards them and they kick it at the goal.

It's also worth noting that sports writers have to find years worth of new ways to phrase "the man kicked the ball into the goal" and describe, in just a few sentences, the feeling of being at a game, so they often choose very floral or metaphorical language. You probably wouldn't describe a football goal as 'predatory' in every day conversation.

A player positioned in front of the opponent's goal mouth is considered to be in a position of strength, like a predator.
This differs from a player having gone through building up right from the middle of the pitch (as in Delap's second goal).
A predatory strike is associated with the first case described above.  It has a sense or component of  exploiting the goalkeeper's
inability to handle the goalmouth melee.  Delap's first goal has this sense.
A predatory strike may also involve capitalising on the goalkeeper's momentary lapse in concentration (which wasn't the case in the recent Ipswich v Villa match).

An animal preying on another involves a violent attack. Presumably this player suddenly kicked the ball very hard into the goal when the other team weren't expecting it.
